# Plotting by column with grid_arrange_shared_legend

Tags: r, plot

In R, with grid_arrange_shared_legend(), I'm able to set the number of columns and rows. The function plots by row. Is there a way to set it so that it plots by row?

Comment: if it plots by row by default, you dont have to set it. can u give an example of your code? I am not sure if anyone can help without code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example